# SVG Animation Color Transition

Tags: css, animation, svg

Hi guys i am trying to make a rectangle using SVG where the background color changes using css animation. Its working in chrome but not Firefox or IE, is there any work around this or solution?

Here is the fiddle as an example

HTML Code

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 202 197"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<defs>
<linearGradient y2="0" x2="1" y1="1" x1="1" id="green">
  <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.99609" stop-color="#027d07"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.99609" stop-color="#1ff026"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="red" x1="1" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
  <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.98828" stop-color="#8a0f04"/>
  <stop stop-color="#ff5454" stop-opacity="0.99609" offset="1"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" class="red">
</rect>
```

CSS Code

```
    /* Standard syntax Chrome*/
@-webkit-keyframes pulseRed {
    from {fill:url(#green)}
    to {fill:url(#red)}
}
/* Standard syntax IE and Firefox this is done differently 
because IE and Firefox does not support animation for gradient*/
@keyframes pulseRed {
  from {fill:url(#green)}
  to {fill:url(#red)}
}
.red
{
 -webkit-animation: pulseRed 2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: pulseRed 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulseRed 2s infinite;
        animation: pulseRed 2s infinite;
}
```

To add on on IE and Firefox, they both show a black box

jsFiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/cyj89/zPuGz/

Comment: I've tried another way by using animate option in SVG here is my fiddle but the effect is not what i want 
http://jsfiddle.net/yFthP/23/

Comment: still have not gotten a solution. anyone?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use vendor prefixes for respective browsers

try this

```
.red{
-webkit-animation: pulsered 2s infinite;
   -moz-animation: pulsered 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulsered 2s infinite;
        animation: pulsered 2s infinite;

}
```

Comment: I have already added the animation prefix for IE but it did not work, i have also updated my code to reflect checking of all other browsers but it still does not work